# ie7 problems with Jquery, possily html too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm working on a website for a local enterprise charity and I'm having problems getting everything to work in ie7.  It works on every other browser I've tested, and passes when it goes through w3's validator.

my navigation on the left doesnt work in ie7, the links are there when I look at the  under developer tools (and of course they're there and working in other browsers).

Also the jquery isn't loading properly for the gallery slider, the buttons and the bullets to show which picture is being viewed are there but the images themselves aren't!

Here's the url http://www.youthenterprise.co.uk/newhullready/coded/gallery.php

I have googled an answer the the problem an checked all the little details they suggested (moving the $document.ready which I don't have, making sure it's set at text/javascript instead of application/javascript...)

Comment: Unless it's a client requirement, let me suggest just abandoning IE7 ... http://theie7countdown.com/ , http://maxfoundry.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-ie6-ie7-and-mostly-ie8/

Comment: why do you have double included the orbit-css, outside and inside the conditional comment?
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/orbit-1.2.3/orbit-1.2.3.css">
  <!--[if IE 7.0]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/ie7.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/orbit-1.2.3/orbit-1.2.3.css">
<![endif]-->
`

Comment: oh I added that into the ie7 if in case that was why it wasn't reading the stylesheet right, I'll remove it.  The client themselves are local council based and mostly are still stuck on ie7 themselves and most of the schools they work with will be using it too so I do need to find a solution unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed you have this in the orbit-1.2.3.css, line 3-11

```
#featured, 1,2,3,4,5 { 
    width: 620px;
    height: 450px;
    background: #fff url('orbit/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
#featured, 1,2,3,4,5>img,  
#featured, 1,2,3,4,5>div,
#featured, 1,2,3,4,5>a { display: none; }
```

This is causing the first slider (also named #featured) to break. I'm not 100% sure where this code is being used but if you delete/comment it out, it should fix your IE7 issue.

Or if you need that code, rename the ID of the first slider.

Hope that helps.

Thanks
Gillian

EDIT: Also forgot to mention, you don't need to add the scripts for each slider, you can add them to the head tag :)

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Hull Ready - the future is ours</title>

<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/orbit-1.2.3/orbit-1.2.3.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="style/orbit-1.2.3/jquery.orbit-1.2.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style/ie7.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('#featured').orbit();
$('#featured1').orbit();
$('#featured2').orbit();
$('#featured3').orbit();
});
</script>
</head>
```